# Android: initializing a list with a large number of items

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio, android-resources

I need to use a list with more than 31 thousand strings for a dropdown menu. Now, if I declare this List/Array in java, I get the error that says the code is too large to compile. On the other hand, if I put these values in `string-array` in strings.xml, I get the message `Resource compilation failed` when I try to build the application.

What else can be done to store this list?

I don't want to keep the data in server and fetch it using API because it will increase my server cost.

Comment: a drop-down with 31000 items, glad I am not your user.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I can't find any better approach to my requirement. although it's a dropdown, user can just type and find the item they need

Comment: You could put the data into a table in a local SQLite Database (no servers needed), and then retrieve only the visible part when needed. I suggest to use a recyclerView to show the list of item: it needs a bit more time to be implemented, but works very well with big lists of data.

Comment: @Graziano but even if I follow this approach, I need to declare this list somewhere first. that's where I'm facing the build related issues.

Comment: Assuming that the list is static, you can include a pre-filled Database in your assets folder and copy it into the /databases folder when your application first launches. No need to fill it by the app using big arrays.

Comment: @Graziano your comment really helped. can you please share this approach in the answer section so that I can mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the data into a table in a local SQLite Database (no servers needed), and then retrieve only the visible part when needed. I suggest to use a `RecyclerView` to show the list of item: it needs a bit more time to be implemented, but works very well with big lists of data.

Assuming that the list is static, you can include a pre-filled Database in your assets folder and copy it into the `/databases` folder when your application first launches. No need to fill it by the app using big arrays.